# Refreshing Windows Forms controls between actions in a 'for' loop

Tags: c#, windows, controls

I have a problem that I don't want to work with multithreaded applications since I am testing some code, and I need it single threaded.

It's updating the textbox only after it's all done. I need to somehow keep it updated all the time. Is there another way except with a second thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
// in for loop
tbxMyTextBox.Text = "New text!";
tbxMyTextBox.Refresh();
```

I remember having to do something similar in the past.

Answer (score 1):

> It's updating the textbox only after it's all done. I need to somehow keep it updated all the time. Is there another way expect with a second thread?

There isn't a *good* way to do this. The problem is, if you're executing code on the UI thread, the UI thread can't process the messages in the message pump, including the ones that way to refresh the TextBox, until your work completes.

In Windows Forms, you can force the application to process these messages by calling [Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), but this is really a bad, bad idea. It's much better (and safer!) to use a `BackgroundWorker` or some other multithreading technique to push the work into the background thread instead.